# How to save user input between his messages in Laravel for telegram bot

Tags: php, laravel, bots, telegram, messenger

How to save on server side - variables data, or user input between his messages in Laravel, for telegram bot. For example, save selected before menu items, for each user. Or save user input, and after all steps complete, collect full user data for new order creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own code in PHP and store the data in MySQL database, for example. 
But this will not work so fast compared to
using a turnkey solution. 
**shapoapps/multibot_driver** package (composer require shapoapps/multibot_driver) https://github.com/shapoapps/multibot_driver 
The package includes the functionality of the session manager for messenger users. Same as sessions for web browser users. When you receive new message - save data in the session. When you need this data later, - retrieve it. 
shapoapps/multibot_driver supports telegram drivers - Irazasyed, Botman.

Comment: The GitHub link is not working now also the repo cannot be found.